# still get binary "<<": no operator found which takes a right-hand with <string>

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

struct phoneBook
{
    string name;
    string address;
    string phoneNumber;
};

void insertName(phoneBook print[])
{
    print[256];
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        cin >> print[i].name;
        cin >> print[i].address;
        cin >> print[i].phoneNumber;
    }
}

void printBook(phoneBook print[])
{
    print[256];
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        cout << print[i];
    }


}

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    cout << "xd";
}
```

in the code shown above, I get an error. The error is `binary "<<": no operator found which takes a right-hand with`.

I have string included as you can see, but it only solves the problem for the `>>` operator. And if you look at the code, in the `void printBook()` I have a `cout` command `cout << print[i];`. That's where the error occurs, not in the `int main(){cout << "xd";}` function. Why does the error not affect the `<<` in int main, but only in `void phoneBook()`? If anyone has a nice solution for this, I'd be more than happy to hear it. Thanks in advance.

(The code you see isn't finished yet, and I am relatively new to C++(sorry if it looks like an abomination and if there are any other errors in the code.).)

Comment: What do you think `print[256];` does? And what do you think `print[i]` is?

Comment: This is off-topic, but relevant: as a rule, don't use C-style arrays (`int foo[42]; phoneBook bar[100];`) in modern C++. (But many older textbooks and guides will still teach this.) Use `std::vector` instead - for example, `std::vector<phoneBook> phoneBooks;`.

Answer (score 3):

```
cout << print[i];
```

The type of `print[i]` is `phoneBook`, not `std::string`.  Your compiler is telling you there's no function defined for putting a `phoneBook` into an output stream.

Either print members one at a time, or define a function

```
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& os, phoneBook book );
```

to make your original line compilable.

Answer (score 2):

This line is causing your compiler error:

```
cout << print[i];
```

You are asking `std::cout` to output a `phoneBook`. This is not possible without implementing an operator for `<<` that takes a `phoneBook`.

Otherwise, you would need to print each field of the `phoneBook` seperately (like you do in `insertName`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in

```
cout << print[i];
```

As others above stated, but there is another way to go around without implementing overriden operator (which is more natural and is the way, you should go) and that is to implement function 
 `std::string phoneBook::toString()`
, which would return string representing the phone book, so your call would look like:

```
cout << print[i].toString();
```